# iphone: [NSNull getCharacters:]: unrecognized selector error using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi when I try to search an entity in core data on certain fields, I get the following error:

```
[NSNull getCharacters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This is code I am using to set predicate:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"jobtitle=%@",@"Barber"];
    searchResults = [getContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

However, when I set the predicate to something I know is true on other fields, the search works correctly:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title=%@",@"Dr"];
    searchResults = [getContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

First version searches on title field/attribute, second on jobtitle field/attribute.

Examining the attributes job and jobtitle in the model, I cannot discern any difference between them.

Can anyone tell me where the NSNull is coming from and what it means?  Could there be something I am missing in the properties of the attributes that would account for this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is `getContacts` a result of executing an `NSFetchRequest`? Is it happens to have its `resultType` set to `NSDictionaryResultType`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like objects in `getContacts` array don't have `jobtitle` property in first method. You can check it by printing the first object `NSLog(@"%@", getContacts.firstObject)` or print the whole array `NSLog(@"%@", getContacts)`

Comment: I think you are right.  I've just realized that the getContacts object I was searching was the wrong object--it is not all the contacts in the MOC but rather a set obtained earlier for a related but slightly different purpose. What is the object that has includes everything grabbed by NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: logging the getContacts array shows that both title and jobtitle have objects where a value is nil: i.e.: jobtitle = \"\";\n     title = \"\";\n